# How to use first order logic to represent the statement below?

Tags: first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I'm trying to represent the following statement in first order logic:

```
Bill Gates funds all those who Stevie Jobs does not fund.
```

Not 100% sure about the correctness of the logic that I'm using here:

```
all x (Funds(Bill Gates,x) & -Funds(Stevie Jobs,x)).
```

Comment: The statement gives the sense that if Steve jobs does not fund someone then Bill Gates would fund him. Hence the correct for 'might be', 

($\forall x$) $\sim$(Steve jobs funds x) $\rightarrow$ (Bill gates funds $x$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > Bill Gates funds all those who Stevie Jobs does not fund.
>
> ```
> all x (Funds(Bill Gates,x) & -Funds(Stevie Jobs,x)).
> ```

Your proposed translation says that nobody is funded by Stevie; on the other hand, the given statement does not preclude somebody from being funded by *both* Bill and Stevie.

Your proposed translation also says that everybody is funded by Bill; on the other hand, the given statement clearly allows for Bill not funding somebody that Stevie funds.

Rewriting the given statement: "All those who Stevie Jobs doesn't fund, Bill Gates funds."

This is a conditional—not a conjunction—statement, and the correct translation is $$\forall x \Big(\lnot S(x)\to B(x)\Big).$$

Comment: If we build a truth table, the case where `S(x) = T` and `B(x) = T` will cause the formula you suggested to return `true`, when it should return `false`, right? In this case we are saying Stevie Jobs funds, Bill Gates funds, and the formula is `true`.

Comment: As explained above, the given statement *does* allow for the case where Mary is funded by *both* Bill and Stevie. The answer that I gave can be read, "Each person that Stevie doesn't fund, Bill funds." A truth table is incapable of dealing with quantified sentences like the above.